# Animate & orientate object along svg path using snap.svg

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I have an animated SVG path
I can attach a polyline to the end of the path which works (commented out in the codepen) but when I attach a custom path the Matrix coordinates disappear below the page.

You can see this in chrome dev tools if you inspect the bottom blue dot and below that there is a 
g transform="matrix(0.8351,0.5501 
If you swap the first coordinates out with 'M246' the feet element will appear (at the end of the animation).
So everthing is working apart from the coordinate mapping is off

Does anyone have any suggestions, thanks in advance
Michael

****Code Pen****
http://codepen.io/michaelcockle/pen/eBCAv?editors=001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you've already spotted an answer, but you need to account for the transform baked into the path itself, so

```
meFeet.transform( 't' + parseInt(movePoint.x - 260) + ',' + parseInt( movePoint.y - 1750) + 'r' + (movePoint.alpha - 90));
```

example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqDtg)

Comment: Yep thats the one, although if i had exported the feet as their own svg with their own bounding box I would not have had to change the coordinates. (they were originally exported as part of the larger map and so were relative to that)